# PHP font_size Captcha issue

Tags: php, gd, captcha

I tried to change the `$font_size` but it seems it is not working. It stays the same no matter what. Even if I altered the `$font_size` up to 130. It stays the same:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: image/png');

    $rand_num = rand(1000, 9999);

    $font_size = 130;

    $image_width = 110;
    $image_height = 20;

    $image = imagecreate($image_width, $image_height);
    imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
    $black_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);

    imagestring($image, $font_size, 0, 0, $rand_num, $black_color);

    for($x=0; $x <= 30; $x++){
        $x1 = rand(1, 100); 
        $y1 = rand(1, 100);
        $x2 = rand(1, 100);
        $y2 = rand(1, 100);

        imageline($image, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $black_color);
    }

    imagepng($image);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [PHP Manual](http://us.php.net/imagestring), The font parameter

> Can be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 for built-in fonts in latin2 encoding (where
>   higher numbers corresponding to larger fonts) or any of your own font
>   identifiers registered with imageloadfont().

So you have to try 1 2 3 4 5 and not 130.

Comment: So the maximum can only be 5 for built-in fonts in latin2 encoding?

Comment: Yes that is correct, or else you can load a custom font using imageloadfont()

Comment: imageloadfont()? Is it the same as imagettftext()?

Answer (score 0):

For built in fonts, font size can be from 1,2,3,4 and 5. Please refer to http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagestring.php

Answer (score 0):

You can change the font size using `imagettftext` function.

```
imagettftext($image, $font_size, $angle, $x, $y, $text_color, '$font-family', $text);

  $image is the $imagecreate function
  $font_size is the size of font you want.
  $angle is the angle of the fonts tilted
  $x and $y are coordinates.
  $text_color is the imagecolorallocate function
  $font-family is the family of font you want to use
  $text is the text or random text to be displayed
```